# Using a #planetary tag for Planetary GIS questions?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags, scope

A subset of the planetary science community uses and develops GIS for scientific research and exploration of the planets and small bodies of our Solar System.

The OpenPlanetary initiative (http://openplanetary.github.io) wants to experiment with the idea of using a specific tag for all planetary scientists and developers to share knowledge within, and benefit from this Geographic Information Systems StackExchange community.

This tag may also be used across other existing StackExchange communities (eg.: astronomy, space exploration).

Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: As described, the proposed 'planetary' tag sounds very meta, maybe because it's just an adjective. It seems to be just an umbrella to cover several other tags we already have, such as geography, geology, geodesy, and exogeography. It'd be like having a 'programmer' tag. Can you perhaps revise with what you'd put as the Wiki to specifically describe what the tag would cover?

Comment: I think that, at best, the jury is still out on this proposal so I am going to set [meta-tag:status-deferred].

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be. Make sure to tag at least two questions when creating it; so it won't automatically go away.

Also, it is nice to write a tag excerpt and tag wiki, as soon, the tag exists. The excerpt needs to be clear about how to use the [planetary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary) tag in GIS SE. It can also contain a brief explanation about the topic. In the tag wiki, perhaps you could expand the explanation about how such subject is related to GIS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is fine but I would like to hear how this proposed tag differs from the [geology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology) tag for which the wiki excerpt is:

> The science of structure, composition and development of Earth and
>   other planets. Mostly concerned with planetary processes and
>   resources.

and also what [planetary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary) questions might be better asked here, and why, than at the alternative suggested by the [geology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology) wiki:

> An alternative Stack Exchange for geology questions, which is
>   currently in beta, is [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

The [On Topic page for Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes:

> The Earth Science Stack Exchange is for questions related to earth
>   science disciplines.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - meteorology
> - geophysics
> - geology
> - climatology
> - oceanography
> - geochemistry
> - hydrology
>
> then you are in the right place. The above list is not exhaustive, so
>   if you feel your question is about earth science, go ahead and post
>   it. You can also ask about these topics in reference to other planets
>   that fall under the umbrella of planetary science. You are also
>   welcome to ask questions about techniques or data sources related to
>   these disciplines.

Comment: I know one class of questions that may better asked here. Planetary protection questions may be better here then geology. Maybe planetary remote sensing as well.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder whether industry/discipline tags, like [tag:geology] and [tag:planetary], might be better named [tag:geology-gis] and [tag:planetary-gis] to emphasise that it is only the "GIS end" of geology and planetary science that are on-topic for [gis.se].